# Unable to import @using System.DirectoryServices in razor view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

[image]
I am trying to import the System.DirectoryServices in _Layout.cshtml razor view in .net MVC. But it gives me an error and I also added System.DirectoryServices from reference manager but still it gives an error, what else can I do regarding this problem ??

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Does not exist in the namespace 'System' but in my web.config file bellow code is available          <addnamespace="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" />

Comment: @RasinduDeAlwis post imported code in _Layout.cshtml page

Comment: Image is added.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a target framework problem.
Try to switch to '.NET Framework 4.5'.

Comment: I am trying to get current user's Full name using windows identity that's why I need above code.bellow is the code that I am using to get windows name.Do you have another solution for this                                                                           
                                                                                    @using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)){
    var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
    var firstName = principal.GivenName;
    var lastName = principal.Surname;
}